# Don't Starve Console won't go away?

Tags: technical-issues, dont-starve

I thought just for fun I'd enter in some commands, but ever since I haven't been able to remove the console.

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd>, disabling it. Nothing.

I can remove it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> for a brief time until I click with my mouse then it brings it up again.

I even exited my world and shut the game down and it's still doing this. It's kind of annoying and prevents me from being able to play the game.

Comment: http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Console maybe disable it in settings.ini? I don't have the game so I can't confirm.

Comment: I disabled it. Still there somehow.

Comment: There a world file? You could copy it over, reinstall, drop back in.

Comment: I don't know, but it's happening on all worlds. Old ones and newly created ones.

Comment: It's worth disabling all your mods to check if mods are the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check the settings in your Documents/Klei folder, and make sure that `ENABLECONSOLE` is `false`:

```
[MISC]
ENABLECONSOLE = false
...
```

Next, check that all your files are intact. It could be that somehow your `scripts/constants.lua` got damaged. Make sure that the values of the following three constants are still valid:

```
CONTROL_OPEN_DEBUG_CONSOLE = 42
CONTROL_TOGGLE_LOG = 43
CONTROL_TOGGLE_DEBUGRENDER = 44
```

Last, but not least, make sure that it's not a *configuration* problem. Go into your settings menu, then controls, and click on the right arrow till you get to the last page. Make sure that the debug/console/log functionalities aren't bound to wrong keys or even a mouse button.